# Tikz plot precision

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi I would like to plot the following function $3-x\cdot\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}$ using tikz.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[dotted] (-2.5,-2) -- (-2.5,2);
\draw (-2.5,0) node[below]{-5};
\draw[dotted] (2.5,-2) -- (2.5,2);
\draw (2.5,0) node[below]{5};
\draw[gray] (2.6,0.5) node[right]{$y=1$};
\draw[red] (2.6,-1.6) node[right]{$y=1-\tfrac{1}{6}x^2$};
\draw[blue] (2.6,-1) node[right]{$y=f(x)$};
\draw[scale=0.5,domain=-5:5,smooth,variable=\x,gray] plot ({\x},{1});
\draw[scale=0.5,domain=-5:5,smooth,variable=\x,red] plot ({\x},{1-\x*\x/6});
\draw[scale=0.5,domain=-10:10,samples=150,smooth,variable=\x,blue,] plot ({\x},{3-\x*(exp(\x)+1)/(exp(\x)-1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output

[image]

Obviously this is not the correct graph and I believe the problem is due to the precision. How can I improve the presion of the plot? It seems that simply adjust `samples` does not resolve the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Your function is defined at x=0?

Comment: When one repairs your code by adding the missing semicolons, it gives (as expected) `dimension too large` errors. You may want to use `pgfplots`.

Comment: Why you need the rest of graph outside the dots?

Comment: No apparently it's not defined at x=0, but that does not seem to be a problem here.... I'm making this graph to show the behavior of this function near zero but I would also like to show its asymptotic behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments! I used ```pgfplots``` and it worked. So this cannot be done using simply the ```plot``` function?

Comment: I think I'm late, but I edited your given code because it has some errors. Try to put a Minimal Working Example that reproduces your error next time.

Comment: Ok sorry I haven't posted here before. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure I understand why the points at plus or minus 2.5 are labeled plus or minus 5, but the following at least has no `dimension too large` errors. Just switch on `fpu` for that plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
        \draw[dotted] (-2.5,-2) -- (-2.5,2);
        \draw (-2.5,0) node[below]{-5};
        \draw[dotted] (2.5,-2) -- (2.5,2);
        \draw (2.5,0) node[below]{5};
        \draw[gray] (2.6,0.5) node[right]{$y=1$};
        \draw[red] (2.6,-1.6) node[right]{$y=1-\tfrac16x^2$};
        \draw[blue] (2.6,-1) node[right]{$y=f(x)$};
        \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-5:5,smooth,variable=\x,gray]
            plot ({\x},{1});
        \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-5:5,smooth,variable=\x,red]
            plot ({\x},{1-\x*\x/6});
        \begin{scope}   
         \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
        \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-10:10,samples=150,smooth,variable=\x,blue]
            plot ({\x},{3-\x*(exp(\x)+1)/(exp(\x)-1)});
        \end{scope} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that if you ignore error messages in LaTeX, you cannot expect to get reasonable output. (While I am aware of the fact that overleaf is good at hiding errors, but I do not support this practice.) Anyway, I'd recommend `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
        domain=-5:5,ymax=2,ymin=-3,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,axis equal,
        smooth,samples=150,clip=false]
        \draw[dotted] (-2.5,-2) -- (-2.5,2);
        \draw (-2.5,0) node[below]{-5};
        \draw[dotted] (2.5,-2) -- (2.5,2);
        \draw (2.5,0) node[below]{5};
        \addplot[color=gray,samples=2] {1} 
            node[pos=1,sloped,above left]{$y=1$};
        \addplot[color=red] {1-x*x/6}
            node[pos=1,sloped,below left] {$y=1-\tfrac16x^2$};
        \addplot[color=blue] {3-x*(exp(x)+1)/(exp(x)-1)}
            node[pos=1,sloped,above left] {$y=f(x)$};
 \end{axis}         
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use an odd number of samples, which usually is a good choice for symmetric plots, you need to, as [pointed out by C.F.G](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536520/tikz-plot-precision#comment1355487_536520), come up with an analytic continuation of the function at `x=0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The labels are because I'm using a scale of 0.5... I agree that using ```pgfplots``` seems easier.